# IOS SDK + Emoji Keyboard disable and enable multi language

Tags: ios, keyboard, emoji, multilingual

I am working on one app, in which i need multi language support but i want to disable emoji keyboard.

I have tried `UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable` type of keyboard but it also disable multi language support.

Can you please provide any suggestion do allow multi-language and disable emoji keyboard.

Thanks